# Disown a job currently running under another shell

Tags: linux, centos, nohup

At location A I started a process that will be running on a server over the night. I never disowned this process nor did I use nohup. =\

I am now at location B and I want to keep this process running but I want to kill the shell and logout at location A.

Is it possible to do what I want from location B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [reptyr](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/). But since neercs is not what you want, which can also grab processes from another shell, maybe reptyr does not help you, too.

Of course, after moving the application to your new shell,  you need to kill the old one to logout.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [neercs](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/neercs) a shot.

Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YkQ8gI575U) showing how it works.

It's supposed to very unstable, though, and isn't packaged in CentOS or Debian-based distributions.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. =\ Thanks anyways.

Comment: Can you please clarify why neercs (or repytr) isn't what you want? This may help people come up with a solution.

Comment: Sorry, it's not what I'm looking for cause I can't install neercs.